Can I ask questions about research journals?
Can I ask for a list of journals that are good enough to publish research work based on the topic related to cryptography?
I didn't see journal tag, hence I am thinking that it is not a place to ask about publishing etc., but only related to the research doubts etc.,

Hmm, if you look at the title of your question then I'd say "yes" because you can certainly ask about topics within research journals. But for lists I unfortunately agree with e-sushi. Thanks for asking though, it's a good meta topic.

Academia might be a good place to ask about how to find a good journal to publish your work in (if that question hasn't been answered before, which is likely). Asking about specific journals is probably off-topic there as well, though.

No.
Generally, there aren’t many SE sites that allow such list-questions and Crypto.SE is no exception.
In fact, we even have an according close-reason which I’ll simply quote for informational purposes:

Requests for literature, software or similar recommendations are off-topic here. For details, see: Do we want “literature recommendations” and similar “list/subjective questions”?

If you follow the link, you’ll not only notice that that was the first question here at Crypto.SE meta, but you’ll also find the reasoning behind it.
